# remove disks from active lvm

Tags: linux, lvm

Have anybody experienced removing hard drives from active LVM group, and put them back after a while?
(By remove I mean physical remove or remove from VM configuration if you use virtualization)

Is there any chance that data will not be completely corrupt?

Comment: In that very case you're talking bout NOT removing from active LVM — just by definition.

And this would be weird in any case, so question is kinda pointless.

Comment: What? I don't even...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in LVM this operation stable and no have chance to fail.

Comment: It should be so. But I have to know for sure. Because there some dirty blocks in buffers and so on. Also kernel and lvm itself probably have some tables\descriptors which could brake after this operation.

Comment: Ok, checked this by myself. When you remove physical devices from lvm group,volumes of this group become read-only. And (I do not understand why) the checksum of the files is the same even if I try to check it with one device missing in VG.

Comment: @st0ne_c0ld if you want remove and add, you can make export/import lvm

Comment: I know about the "normal way". But some Friday evening "__it could happen". And it is better to know how exactly the system handle the situation... :)